# Validating arrays in laravel

Tags: laravel

Can anyone please help me , I don't understand this type of validation, I am new to laravel.

```
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
    'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
```

Comment: `email|unique:users` means the input has to be a valid email address, and the address can't already exist in the `users` table

Comment: question is broad. you can study all of them here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

Comment: @symlink can you also please explain the `person.*.email`?

Comment: @jeffigy not sure but it looks like your form is grouped in a certain way with person as a category?

Comment: @symlink honestly, I just saw that in laravel documentation, and I have no idea how to use it. Thank you so much for your help bro.

Answer (score 1):

First string say you must enter email and unique email for user model

Secend string refer to first name is required and must be alongside lastname

Comment: can you also please explain the `person.*.email`?